# MySQL - Find hotels that are available on certain dates

Tags: mysql

I've read many similar questions but haven't been able to make it work for myself. I'm creating a hotel booking system and I wish to list hotels that have atleast one room available on requested booking dates.

Here's my table structure
[image: Table Structure]

And here's the query that I have so far

```
SELECT
  ac.id,
  ac.name,
  ac.link,
  ac.type,
  ac.country,
  co.name AS countryName,
  ac.state,
  st.statename,
  ac.cityid AS cityId,
  ci.name AS cityName,
  ac.addr,
  ac.featuredimage,
  ac.amenities,
  ac.starrating,
  ac.bookings_received,
  ro.roomprice,
  SUM(ro.numberofrooms) AS totalRooms,
  roomsBooked = (
  SELECT
    *,
    SUM(numberofroomsbooked) AS roomsBooked
  FROM
    bookings
  WHERE
    reservationto >= '2016-07-07' AND reservationfrom <= '2016-07-09'
    AND hotelid = ro.hotel
)
FROM
  accomodations ac
JOIN countries co ON ac.country = co.id
JOIN states st ON ac.state = st.id
JOIN city ci ON ci.id = ac.cityid
JOIN room ro ON ac.id = ro.hotel
WHERE
  ac.active = 1 AND ac.delete = 0
GROUP BY
  ac.id
```

I'm new to MySQL and this is really getting out of hand. The idea is to calculate total number of rooms for a hotel and subtract total number of rooms booked between a given date range. Can I get some help on that?

The Sub query

```
      SELECT
        *,
        SUM(numberofroomsbooked) AS roomsBooked
      FROM
        bookings
      WHERE
        reservationto >= '2016-07-07' AND reservationfrom <= '2016-07-09'
        AND hotelid = ro.hotel
```

works perfectly on it's own but not in this one.

Comment: Add some sample data and your expected result is more helpful.

Comment: I'm not able to add my data to sqlfiddle, do you suggest any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Built upon the previous query

```
SELECT
  ac.id,
  ac.name,
  ac.link,
  ac.type,
  ac.country,
  co.name AS countryName,
  ac.state,
  st.statename,
  ac.cityid AS cityId,
  ci.name AS cityName,
  ac.addr,
  ac.featuredimage,
  ac.amenities,
  ac.starrating,
  ac.bookings_received,
  ro.roomprice,
  ro.totalRooms
FROM
  accomodations ac
JOIN countries co ON ac.country = co.id
JOIN states st ON ac.state = st.id
JOIN city ci ON ci.id = ac.cityid
JOIN (
  SELECT
    hotel,
    roomprice,
    SUM(numberofrooms) AS totalRooms
  FROM
    room
  GROUP BY
    hotel
) ro ON ac.id = ro.hotel
JOIN (
  SELECT
    hotelid,
    SUM(numberofroomsbooked) ASroomsBooked
  FROM
    bookings
  WHERE
    reservationto >= '2016-07-07' AND reservationfrom <= '2016-07-09'
  GROUP BY
    hotelid
) bo ON ac.id = bo.hotelid
WHERE
  ac.active = 1 AND ac.delete = 0
GROUP BY
  ac.id
```

Updated query removed inner select and added it as inner join

```
SELECT
  ac.id,
  ac.name,
  ac.link,
  ac.type,
  ac.country,
  co.name AS countryName,
  ac.state,
  st.statename,
  ac.cityid AS cityId,
  ci.name AS cityName,
  ac.addr,
  ac.featuredimage,
  ac.amenities,
  ac.starrating,
  ac.bookings_received,
  ro.roomprice,
  SUM(ro.numberofrooms) AS totalRooms,
  SUM(tm.roomsBooked ) as roomsBooked,
FROM
  accomodations ac
JOIN countries co ON ac.country = co.id
JOIN states st ON ac.state = st.id
JOIN city ci ON ci.id = ac.cityid
JOIN room ro ON ac.id = ro.hotel
(
  SELECT
    hotelid,
    SUM(numberofroomsbooked) AS roomsBooked
  FROM
    bookings
  WHERE
    reservationto >= '2016-07-07' AND reservationfrom <= '2016-07-09'
    group by hotelid
) tm on tm.hotelid=ro.hotel
WHERE
  ac.active = 1 AND ac.delete = 0
GROUP BY
  ac.id
```

Comment: Thanks Mahesh for your help, you were almost correct. I've editted your answer to include the final query that is correctly working with my data. Please accept the edit and I'll mark yours as the correct answer

Comment: please marked this as answer else t will show as unanswered question

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this query? You are grouping by accommodation hotel so, if you use the function SUM with the booked rooms, it should return you the total of booked rooms. I have not tried it.

I hope it solves your problem.

```
SELECT
  ac.id,
  ac.name,
  ac.link,
  ac.type,
  ac.country,
  co.name AS countryName,
  ac.state,
  st.statename,
  ac.cityid AS cityId,
  ci.name AS cityName,
  ac.addr,
  ac.featuredimage,
  ac.amenities,
  ac.starrating,
  ac.bookings_received,
  ro.roomprice,
  SUM(ro.numberofrooms) AS totalRooms,
  SUM(numberofroomsbooked) AS bookedRooms
FROM
  accomodations ac
JOIN bookings b ON ac.id = b.hotelid
JOIN countries co ON ac.country = co.id
JOIN states st ON ac.state = st.id
JOIN city ci ON ci.id = ac.cityid
JOIN room ro ON ac.id = ro.hotel
WHERE
  ac.active = 1 AND ac.delete = 0
  AND reservationto >= '2016-07-07' AND reservationfrom <= '2016-07-09'
GROUP BY
  ac.id;
```